# How to resolve GENERAL_MSG_CAT_SSL_ERROR]connect to host "" failed: [10054] Connection reset by peer" message?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

**Dear Folks,**

Good Day.

We are observing below error messages intermittently while executing in HP PC, which works well and good in Vugen.

Error Message:

> GENERAL_MSG_CAT_SSL_ERROR]connect to host "" failed: [10054]
>   Connection reset by peer"

Could any one have any clue on this?

Responses are really appreciated.

Thanks for your understanding.

**With Regards,**

**Yasir.**

Answer (score 0):

What has your research on 10054 shown you so far?  This is a common issue and there is much lore already written

Answer (score 0):

This two functions together should solve your problem.
        web.set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","TLS1.2");
        web.set_sockets_option("IGNORE_PREMATURE_SHUTDOWN","1");